# Unmarshall xml file, UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field ""

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I was wondering if somebody can help me out. I created a small maven project so you can easily run the test. For testing you can run the JUnit test UnmarshalTest.unmarshalResponse() which fails with a exception.

I'm trying to read a value from a xml element with an attribute but somehow I'm not able to to that. Any idea why?

XML looks like:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <id_lang xlink:href="http://prestashop.local/api/languages/1">57</id_lang>
</prestashop>
```

Thx a lot

/david

[Update] Sorry, I prepared already the code but forgot to upload it ...
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t99zBxN7juA9RgNhS6S9UCCFSYxksnXW

Comment: There are no telepaths here, providing the code samples increases the chances for helpful answer

Comment: Please post the Java code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full message coming back is such as:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class com.smooth.systems.test.TagValue), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "idLang", "href"])
 at [Source: (File); line: 3, column: 76] (through reference chain: com.smooth.systems.test.TestWrapper["id_lang"]->com.smooth.systems.test.TagValue[""])
```

Which points to the `76` in the body of the `<id_lang>` element in the example above - hence the missing field name.

(It is line 3, there's another `<?xml ... ?>` declaration line not seen in the sample xml).

Switching the `@XmlValue` annotation to `@JacksonXmlText` on the owning `TagValue` class seems to work better.

Comment: Thx, that was exactly I was looking for.

Also pointed me to following link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations

Thx a lot!